# operating Frequency detection of network in Android

Tags: android, frequency, umts

Is it possible to detect frequency/band of the connected mobile network programatically in android.
i want to detect whether it is EGSM 900 network or not

Answer (score 0):

Currently (Android 4.4, API level 19) it is not possible to get the frequency you are using.